# Thread interruption - JCIP

Tags: java, multithreading

In the book `Java Concurrency in Practice` Ch 7, page 142, 143, I didn't quite understand 2 statements:

1. "A thread should be interrupted by its owner".
   -However, on p 141, a class extending Thread has exposed
   `public void cancel() { interrupt(); }` and this could be called by any other code!!
2. "Only code that implements a thread's interruption policy may swallow an interruption request."

A crisp, clear, and complete code illustrating the 2 points above, is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The example you are asking about is provided in the JDK itself :). Take a look at `ThreadPoolExecutor::shutdown`

```
public void shutdown() {
    final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
    mainLock.lock();
    try {
        checkShutdownAccess();
        advanceRunState(SHUTDOWN);
        interruptIdleWorkers();
        onShutdown(); // hook for ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor
    } finally {
       mainLock.unlock();
    }
    tryTerminate();
}
```

***1*** `ThreadPoolExecutor`'s threads (`ThreadPoolExecutor::Worker::thread`) are owned exclusively by a `ThreadPoolExecutor` instance.

`ThreadPoolExecutor::shutdown` does not expose any details about threads it runs and how shut them down. All it guarantees is

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are
>   executed, but no new tasks will be accepted.

***2*** Surely you can provide a `ThreadFactory` emitting threads with overridden `interrupt` methods like this:

```
public void BadThread extends Thread{
    public BadThread(Runnable r){
        super(r);
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt(){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

But that would be a disaster because `ThreadPoolExecutor` does not know about your interruption policy (throwing `IllegalArgumentException`). And according to its implementation `interruptIdleWorkers` method or `runWorker` (when discovering that current state is `SHUTDOWN`, but the worker is not yet interrupted) simply fails when interrupting the worker.

So the following program ***may*** (there are some races between retrieving tasks and shutting down) never terminate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ThreadFactory tf = BadThread::new;
    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8, tf);
    es.submit(() -> System.out.println("Test"));
    es.submit(() -> System.out.println("Test")); // I added this entry because of
                                                 // shutdown() and runWorker() are 
                                                 // kind of racy and
    es.shutdown();
}
```